# Where can I find all the themes in \usefonttheme?

Tags: beamer, fonts

Can you give me a link to the documentation of `\usefonttheme`?
Thank you very much.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! I don't believe that there is a specific documentation on `\usefonttheme` alone, but rather contained as (sub)section in the the usual `beamer` documentation.

Comment: You didn't say but this is a `beamer` command see `texdoc beamer` section 18.1

Answer (score 16, accepted):

If you're looking for all possible font themes you can use, or looking for what's in those themes becaue you want to roll your own, you won't find this in the definition of `\userfonttheme`.

The themes are defined in their own files named `beamerfonttheme‹themename›.sty`; beamer's own come in a subdirectory `themes/font`, but that's not neccessary: `\usefonttheme` is a very thin wrapper around `\usepackage`.

FWIW, the font themes that currently come with beamer (i.e. files in `$TEXMF/latex/beamer/themes/font`) are:

- default
- serif
- professionalfonts
- structurebold
- structureitalicserif
- structuresmallcapsserif

and they are documented in section 18.1 of the userguide.

Answer (score 4):

If you want to see different combinations of Beamer in action, here you can switch and see how different combinations of style, color and fonts in LaTeX  looks like: http://deic.uab.es/~iblanes/beamer_gallery/individual/default-default-default.html

Answer (score 3):

This beamer theme matrix allows you to figure out different combo of theme and font

https://hartwork.org/beamer-theme-matrix/

Answer (score 2):

You can find the latest Beamer font themes in their source files [here](https://github.com/josephwright/beamer/tree/main/base/themes/font). Just remove the `beamerfonttheme` prefix and you have the name.

Answer (score 0):

Just put the words between the {} in
`\usetheme{ }`

```
AnnArbor
Antibes
Bergen
Berkeley
Berlin
Boadilla
boxes
CambridgeUS
Copenhagen
Darmstadt
default
Dresden
EastLansing
Frankfurt
Goettingen
Hannover
Ilmenau
JuanLesPins
Luebeck
Madrid
Malmoe
Marburg
Montpellier
PaloAlto
Pittsburgh
Rochester
Singapore
Szeged
Warsaw
```

Comment: from latex cookbook