# How to fix Beamer build errors with Texmaker

Tags: beamer

How to fix Beamer build errors with Texmaker

```
\documentclass[aspectratio=169]{beamer}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{xunicode}
\usepackage{xltxtra}
\setmainfont{Calibri}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\setmainfont{Carlito}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{tikz}
\date{}
\definecolor{noir}{rgb}{0.21176    0.21176    0.21176}
\definecolor{blanc}{rgb}{.91,.91,.91}
\definecolor{rouge}{rgb}{.91,.09,.09}
\definecolor{vert}{HTML}{9ECE63}
\definecolor{bleu}{rgb}{.09,.09,.91}
\setbeamercolor{normal text}{fg=blanc}
\setbeamercolor{normal text}{fg=white,bg=noir}
\setbeamercolor{structure}{fg=-bleu}
\setbeamercolor{local structure}{fg=bleu}
\setbeamercolor{block title}{fg=vert,bg=}
\setbeamercolor{block body}{bg=}
\setbeamercolor{block title alerted}{bg=,fg=blanc}
\setbeamercolor{block body alerted}{bg=noir!90!blanc}
\setbeamercolor{block title example}{bg=-rouge!45!blanc,fg=blanc}
\setbeamercolor{block body example}{bg=noir!90!blanc}
\setbeamercolor{item}{fg=vert}
\setbeamercolor{frametitle}{fg=vert,bg=}
\setbeamercolor{framesubtitle}{fg=vert,bg=}
\setbeamercolor{subtitle}{fg=vert,bg=}
\setbeamercolor{title}{fg=vert,bg=}
\setbeamercolor{palette primary}{bg=,fg=blanc}
\setbeamercolor{palette secondary}{bg=,fg=bleu!50!blanc}
\setbeamercolor{palette tertiary}{bg=,fg=-vert}
\setbeamercolor{palette quaternary}{use=item,bg=,fg=item.fg}

\setbeamercolor{sidebar}{use=block body, bg=block body.bg}
\setbeamercolor{palette sidebar primary}{use=titlelike, bg=titlelike.bg, fg=titlelike.fg}
\setbeamercolor{section in sidebar}{use=titlelike, fg=titlelike.fg, bg=titlelike.bg}
\setbeamertemplate{blocks}[default]
\setbeamercolor{block title}{bg=}
\setbeamercolor{block body}{bg=}
\setbeamercolor{logo}{use=block title, bg=block title.bg}
\setbeamercolor{separation line}{fg=blanc,bg=blanc}
\setbeamerfont{frametitle}{size=\bf\fontsize{16}{1}\selectfont}
\setbeamerfont{framesubtitle}{size=\bf\fontsize{11}{2}\selectfont}
\setbeamerfont{title}{size=\bf\fontsize{26}{16}\selectfont}
\setbeamerfont{subtitle}{size=\fontsize{26}{12}\selectfont}
\setbeamerfont{normal text}{size=\fontsize{21}{8}\selectfont}
\setbeamerfont{block title}{size=\bf\fontsize{16}{1}\selectfont}
\setbeamertemplate{title}{
    \vspace{0.3cm}
\begin{center}
        \insettitle
\end{center}
}
\setbeamertemplate{frametitle}{
    \vspace*{1.5cm}\hspace*{0.2cm}\insertframetitle \vspace*{0.1cm}}
\setbeamersize{text margin left=2.25cm,text margin right=2cm}
\definecolor{MyBackground}{rgb}{0.21176    0.21176    0.21176}
\setbeamercolor{background canvas}{bg=MyBackground}
\setbeamertemplate{itemize item}[triangle]

\author[JD]{John Doe}

\setbeamertemplate{frametitle}{
    \vspace*{1.5cm}\hspace*{0cm}\insertframetitle \vspace*{0.1cm}}
\setbeamertemplate{framesubtitle}{
    \vspace*{1.5cm}\hspace*{0cm}\insertframesubtitle \vspace*{0.1cm}}
\setbeamertemplate{frametitle}[default][center]
\setbeamersize{text margin left=2.5cm,text margin right=2cm}
\setbeamertemplate{blocktitle}{
    \vspace*{1.5cm}\hspace*{0.2cm}\insertblocktitle \vspace*{b0.1cm}}
\setbeamertemplate{title}{
    \vspace*{1.5cm}\hspace*{0.2cm}\inserttitle \vspace*{0.1cm}}
\setbeamertemplate{background canvas}{bg=noir}
\setbeamertemplate{background canvas}{\includegraphics[width=\paperwidth,height=\paperheight]{ocean2.jpg}}
\setbeamertemplate{itemize item}[triangle]
\setbeamertemplate{frametitlecontinuation}{\insertcontinuationcount}
\setbeamertemplate{text normal}{centring}
\useoutertheme{sidebar}
\setbeamertemplate{farmetitle}{
    \vskip1cm
    \tikz[remember picture,overlay]{
        \node(a)[fill=black,rectangle,minimum width=10cm,minimum height=10cm,anchor=north west]at(current page.north west){};
        \node(b)[anchor=west]at(a.west){\strut\insertframetitle};
        \draw[red, line width = 1mm, below left=1cm and 3cm of a](a.south west)--+(11.8,0);
    }
    \vskip-1cm 
}
\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{
    \insertslidenavigationsymbol
    \insertframenavigationsymbol
    \insertsubsectionnavigationsymbol
    \insertsectionnavigationsymbol
    \insertdocnavigationsymbol
    \insertbackfindforwardnavigationsymbol
}
\setbeamercolor{proofblock}{use= body,bg=block body.bg}

\newenvironment<>{proofc}[1]
{\begin{actionenv}#2
        \begin{beamercolorbox}[sep=1ex]{proofblock}#1
        }
        {\end{beamercolorbox}\end{actionenv}}
    \setbeamercolor{Exempleblock}{use= body,bg=block body.bg}

    \newenvironment<>{exemplec}[1]
    {\begin{actionenv}#2
            \begin{beamercolorbox}[sep=1ex]{Exempleblock}#1
            }
            {\end{beamercolorbox}\end{actionenv}}

\newtheorem{thm}{Théorème}
\newtheorem{df}{Définition}
%\newtheorem{definition}{Définition}
\newtheorem{rqs}{Remarques}
\newtheorem{rem}{Remarque}
\newtheorem{exmp}{Exemple}
\newtheorem{exemple}{Exemples}
\newtheorem{prop}{Proposition}
\newtheorem{proposition}{Proposition}
\newtheorem{cor}{Corollaire}
\newtheorem{corollaire}{Corollaire}
\newtheorem{lem}{Lemme}
\newtheorem{preuve}{Preuve}
\newcommand{\R}{\mathbb R}
\newcommand{\K}{\mathbb K}
\newcommand{\C}{\mathbb C}
\newcommand{\N}{\mathbb N}
\newcommand{\Sum}{\displaystyle \sum}
\newcommand{\Int}{\displaystyle \int}
\newcommand{\sgn}{\text{sgn}}
%\def\r{\right}
%\def\lf{\left}
%\def\hs{\hspace{0.5cm}}
%\def\dint{\displaystyle\int}
%\def\dlim{\displaystyle\lim}
%\def\dsup{\displaystyle\sup}
%\def\dmin{\displaystyle\min}
%\def\dmax{\displaystyle\max}
%\def\dinf{\displaystyle\inf}
%\def\Proof{\noindent{\bf Proof}\quad}
%\def\ds{\displaystyle}
%\def \ud{\text{d} }
%\def\Id{\mathop{\textrm{Id}}\nolimits} 
%\newcommand{\cadre}[1]{\begin{center}\shadowbox{$#1$}\end{center}}
%\newcommand{\tran}[1]{{\vphantom{#1}}^{\mathit t}{#1}}
%\newcommand{\transpose}[1]{{\vphantom{#1}}^{\mathit t}{#1}}
%\newcommand{\trans}[1]{{\vphantom{#1}}^{\mathit t}{#1}}
%\newcommand{\transp}[1]{{\vphantom{#1}}^{\mathit t}{#1}}
%\newcommand{\trace}[1]{\rm{tr}{(#1)}}
%\newcommand{\diag}[1]{\mbox{diag}\left(#1\right)}
%\newcommand{\pmatrice}[1]{\begin{pmatrix} #1 \end{pmatrix}}
%\newcommand{\amatrice}[1]{\left[\begin{matrix} #1 \end{matrix}\right]}
%\newcommand{\matrice}[1]{\begin{matrix} #1 \end{matrix}}
%\newcommand{\determinant}[1]{\left|\begin{matrix} #1 \end{matrix}\right|}
%\newcommand{\system}[1]{\left\{\begin{matrix} #1 \end{matrix}\right.}
%\newcommand{\systeme}[1]{\left\{\begin{matrix} #1 \end{matrix}\right.}
%\newcommand{\GL}[2]{\rm{GL}_{#1}\left( \mathbb #2\right)}
%\newcommand{\SL}[2]{\rm{SL}_{#1}\left( \mathbb #2\right)}
%\newcommand{\Mc}[2]{\mathcal M_{#1}\left( \mathbb #2\right)}
%\newcommand{\Mnp}[3]{\mathcal M_{#1,#2}\left( \mathbb #3\right)}
%\newcommand{\Mn}[2]{\mathcal M_{#1}\left( \mathbb #2\right)}
\def \MnC {\mathcal M_n (\mathbb C)}
\def \MnR {\mathcal M_n (\mathbb R)}
\def \MnK {\mathcal M_n (\mathbb K)}
%\def \com {\rm {com }}
%\newcommand{\colmat}[2]{#2_{#1}}
%\newcommand{\Mat}[2] {{\rm Mat}_{#1}\left(#2\right)}
%\newcommand{\matc}[3]{#2=\left( #3_{ij}\right)_{1\leqslant i,j\leqslant #1}}
%\newcommand{\matnp}[3]{\left( #3_{ij}\right)_{1\leqslant i\leqslant #1\atop 1\leqslant j\leqslant #2}}
%\newcommand{\seveng}[1]{{\rm Vect}\left(#1\right)}
%\newcommand{\linnpk}[3]{\mathcal L\left({#3}^{#1},{#3}^{#2}\right)}
%\newcommand{\lin}[2]{\mathcal L\left({#1},{#2}\right)}
%\newcommand{\interv}[2]{\ensuremath{\left[\hspace{-0.3ex}\left[ #1,#2\right] \hspace{-0.3ex}\right]}}
%\newcommand{\dim}{\mathop{\mathrm{dim}}\nolimits}
%\def \im {\mbox{Im}}
%
%\numberwithin{equation}{section} \allowdisplaybreaks
%\DeclareMathOperator{\divg }{div} operateur  divergence

\title{Le dahut}


%\author[Radin]{Ethiem Radin}
%\institute[Univ. Gévaudan]{UFR de Biologie\\ Université du Gévaudan}
%\date[MDCCXLVI]{Rencontres Quinte Essence, MDCCXLVI}
\logo{\includegraphics[width=1.3cm]{ccby.png}}

\usefonttheme{Calibri}
\geometry{bottom=0cm, left=2cm, right=2cm,top=0cm}
\begin{document}


\chapter{\Large{séries entières}}

%\begin{thm}
%Soit $f:I\mapsto \mathbb{R}$ continue telle que
%\end{thm}

\textbf{Définition} : \newline
\begin{itemize}
\item On appelle série entière de la variable complexe $z$ de coefficients $(a_n)_n$ la série (de fonctions) $\displaystyle \underset{n\geq 0}{\dsum }a_{n}z^{n}$. 
\item On appelle série entière de la variable réelle $x$ de coefficients $(a_n)_n$ la série (de fonctions) $
\displaystyle \sum a_{n}x^{n}.$

\end{itemize}
Remarque

1. Un polyn\^{o}me est une sèrie entière dont les coefficients sont
nuls $\grave{\text{\`{a}}}\text{\`{a}partir d'un certain rang }$.

3. La sèrie entière $\sum a_{n}x^{n}$ converge au moins pour $z=0$;
sa somme est pour $z=0$ est ègal \`{a} $a_{0}.$

{\textbf{Lemme d'Abel}}

\begin{thm}
Soit $\displaystyle \sum a_{n}z^{n}$ \textit{une sèrie entière et} $z_{0}\in \mathbb{C}$, alors les propositions suivantes sont équivalentes
\begin{itemize}
\item La suite $(a_{n}z_{0}^{n})$.
\item La sèrie $\sum_{n\geq }a_{n}z^{n}$ converge pour tout complexe $z$ tel que $|z|\leq |z_{0}|$
\end{itemize}
\end{thm}

\begin{thm}
Soit $\displaystyle \sum a_{n}z^{n}$ \textit{une sèrie entière et} $z_{0}$ un complexe non nul tel que la suite $(a_{n}z_{0}^{n})$ soit bornée.

Pour tout complexe} $z$ : $a_{n}z^{n}=O(|\displaystyle \frac{z}{z_{0}}|^{n})$ .Pour tout complexe} $z$ \textit{tel que} $|z|<|z_{0}|$, \textit{la sèrie numérique} $\displaystyle \sum a_{n}z^{n}$ est
absolument convergente.
\end{thm}

\textbf{Thèorème \ :[Lemme d'Abel ]}

\textit{Soit} $\displaystyle \sum a_{n}z^{n}$ \textit{une série entière et} $z_{0}$ \textit{un complexe non nul tel que la suite} $(a_{n}z_{0}^{n})$ soit bornée.

\begin{enumerate}
\item \textit{Pour tout complexe} $z$ : $a_{n}z^{n}=O\left( \left \vert \frac{
z}{z_{0}}\right \vert ^{n}\right) $ .

\item \textit{Pour tout complexe} $z$ \textit{tel que} $|z|<|z_{0}|$, 
\textit{la sèrie numèrique} $\displaystyle \sum a_{n}z^{n}$ \textit{
est absolument convergente}.
\end{enumerate}

\textbf{Démonstration }

\begin{enumerate}
\item Pour tout $z\in \mathbb{C}$ : $|a_{n}z^{n}|=\left \vert
a_{n}z_{0}^{n}\right \vert \left \vert \frac{z}{z_{0}}\right \vert ^{n}=O\left(
\left \vert \frac{z}{z_{0}}\right \vert ^{n}\right) .$

\item Si $|z|<|z_{0}|$, la sèrie gèomètrique $\displaystyle \sum
\left \vert \frac{z}{z_{0}}\right \vert ^{n}$ converge, donc la sèrie $
\displaystyle \sum |a_{n}z^{n}|$ converge ègalement : la sèrie $
\displaystyle \sum a_{n}z^{n}$ est absolument convergente.
\end{enumerate}

\subsection{Rayon de convergence}

Soit $\displaystyle \sum a_{n}z^{n}$ une sèrie entière. L'ensemble
des rèels positifs $r$ tels que la suite $(a_{n}r^{n})_{n}$ soit born
èe

est un intervalle contenant $0.$

{\textbf{Définition}}
On appelle rayon de convergence de la série entière $\displaystyle \sum a_{n}z^{n}$ par : 
$$ R=\sup \{r\in \mathbb{R}_{+},(a_{n}r^{n})bornée}.$$
Si $R=0$, alors pour tout $z$ non nul,la suite $(a_{n}z^{n})$ n'est pas bornée.


\textbf{Exemple 1.}

$\displaystyle \sum n^{n}z^{n}$ est grossièrement$t$ divergente pour tout $z\in \mathbb{C}^{\ast }.$

$\bullet $ Si $R=+\infty $ : la suite $(a_{n}r^{n})$ est bornèe pour tout $r\in \mathbb{R}^{+}.$ Pour tout complexe $z$, il existe $r\in \mathbb{R}+\mathrm{t}\mathrm{e}1$ que $|z|<r$

: la sèrie $\displaystyle \sum a_{n}z^{n}$ est absolument convergente pour tout $z\in \mathbb{C}.$

\textbf{Exemple 1}$\displaystyle \sum \frac{z^{n}}{n!}$ est absolument 
\textit{convergente pour tout} $z\in \mathbb{C}$, car \textit{la suite} $(
\displaystyle \frac{z^{n}}{n!})$ \textit{converge} vers $0$, \textit{et} est 
\textit{donc} bornèe.

$\bullet $ Si $0<R<+\infty $:

\begin{itemize}
\item Pour tout $z\in \mathbb{C}$ tel que $|z|<R$, il existe un rèel $r$ strictement compris entre $|z|$ et $R$ tel que la suite $(a_{n}r^{n})_{n}$ soit bornèe : la sèrie $\displaystyle \sum a_{n}z^{n}$ est absolument convergente.

\item Pour tout $z\in \mathbb{C}$ tel que $|z|>R$, la suite $\left(a_{n}z^{n}\right) _{n}$ n'est pas bornèe: la sèrie $\displaystyle\sum a_{n}z^{n}$ est grossièrement divergente.

\item Pour $|z|=R$, on ne peut rien dire a priori de la sèrie $\displaystyle \sum a_{n}z^{n}$ : elle peut \^{e}tre convergente (absolumentou non), ou divergente (grossièrement ou non).
\end{itemize}

\textbf{Dèfinition}

Le disque ouvert de centre $O$ de rayon $R$ est appelè disque de
convergence; $\left] -R,R\right[ $ l'intervalle de convergence.

\begin{itemize}
\item A l'intèrieur du disque de convergence, la sèrie converge
absolument.

\item A l'extèrieur du disque de convergence, la sèrie diverge grossi
èrement.

\item Sur le cercle de convergence, on ne peut gènèralement rien
dire.

\item Cependant deux rèsultats importants \`{a} retenir .

\begin{enumerate}
\item Si la sèrie converge absolument en un point du cercle, elle
converge absolument sur tout le cercle.

\item Si la sèrie diverge grossièrement en un point du cercle, elle
diverge grossièrement sur tout le cercle.
\end{enumerate}
\end{itemize}

\bigskip

Soit $\displaystyle \sum a_{n}z^{n}$ une sèrie entière de rayon de
convergence $R>0.$

\begin{itemize}
\item Si la sèrie $\displaystyle \sum a_{n}z_{0}^{n}$ converge, alors
alors $R\geq \left \vert z_{0}\right \vert .$

\item Si la sèrie $\displaystyle \sum a_{n}z_{1}^{n}$ diverge , alors $
R\leq \left \vert z_{1}\right \vert .$

\item Si la suite $\left( a_{n}z_{0}^{n}\right) _{n}$ ne tend pas vers $0$,
alors sèrie $\displaystyle \sum a_{n}z^{n}$ converge pour $z=z_{0}$,
alors $R\geq \left \vert z_{0}\right \vert .$
\end{itemize}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Please try to make your code more minimal. Most likely the majority of the code is unrelated to the error itself and could be omitted for this question. Please also quote the error message you get

Comment: `\documentclass[aspectratio=169]{beamer}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\newcommand{\C}{\mathbb C}
\usefonttheme{Calibri}

\begin{document}
\end{document}` should be enough to reproduce teh error messages.

Comment: Either use `polyglossia` of `babel` not a combination of both. Regarding the `\C` command you might want to have a look here [Single letter macros](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/316391/134144). Regarding the ùsefonttheme`: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/211264/134144 and https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/79420/134144

Comment: also never use any of these with luatex or xetex `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}`

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it was solved in the comments.